# how to set CSRF cookie in nextjs for django

Tags: django, typescript, next.js, cookies, next.js14

I'm new to Nextjs and I'm working on a frontend for my Django app

here's my route.js that calls the django endpoint

```
import { NextResponse  } from 'next/server';
import axios from 'axios';
//import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { imageData } = req.body;
  try {

    //Django backend

    const response = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:8000/souci/capture/', 
      { imageData }
    );

    return NextResponse.json({response});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending image data to Django:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to send image data to Django' });
  }
}

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  //return
}
```

I'm currently getting this error on my Django console

```
WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /souci/capture/
[20/Feb/2024 04:55:44] "POST /souci/capture/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2870
```

how do I set the csrftoken in the POST function?

I've tried a couple things include settings axios defaults

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
```

creating a cookie (though not sure how to add this to the POST request)

```
cookies().set('csrftoken', 'souci', {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24, //one day in seconds
  httpOnly: true, // prevent client-side access
  sameSite: 'strict',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `csrf_token` with this Javascript function

```
function getToken(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

const csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit new to this. where does this go? I put this function in route.ts, which is where the code in my question sits and it says document is not defined... which seems to mean this is supposed to go in the nextjs frontend (.tsx) file